# Concurrency in Practice > Listing 4.13

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

Here is a snippet from page 72:

```
@ThreadSafe
public class BetterVector<E> extends Vector<E> {
  public synchronized boolean putIfAbsent(E x) {
    boolean absent = !contains(x);
    if (absent)
      add(x);
    return absent;
  }
}
```

According to Brian the above class is thread safe. But as you can see that `E x` is really a mutable class. What would happen if after evaluating `absent` to `true` the value of `x` changes? Isn't this a violation and might lead to pretty nasty bugs?

Comment: You can replicate the issue in a single thread execution. Add two elements, then change one of them to be the same as the other. So it's not really about thread safety. "Thread safe" doesn't mean "you won't have ANY KIND of bugs in this code".

Comment: BTW "But as you can see that E x is really a mutable class." is not quite corrct, as you cannot see that. It could be an immutable class as well.

Comment: `E` is not bound to any class so it's not inherently unsafe. It only becomes unsafe if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct.  But that is not an issue with threaded code or concurrency.  That's a computer science type problem dealing with references and pointers in general.  A reference points to an object.  If you pass references around, as Java does, then those references can be used to access the underlying object.